# Ansible: How print number instead string in JSON - module uri

Tags: json, ansible, uri

---

Hi,
I need to print a variable as a number instead a string.
Example:

```
- name: Create input
  uri:
    url: "https://{{ url_graylog }}/api/system/inputs"
    ...
    body_format: json
    body:
      title: "{{ name }}"
      configuration:
      bind_address: "0.0.0.0"
      port: "{{ port }}"  <-- its print as string, I need number
    global: true
```

I tried

```
port: {{ port }}          <-- not work
port: "{{ port | int }}"  <-- not work
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: I found this note. I think the same problem
`Values passed in using the key=value syntax are interpreted as strings. Use the JSON format if you need to pass in anything that shouldn’t be a string (Booleans, integers, floats, lists etc).`

[https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line]

Comment: Is it considered a string because of you have the quotes? Remove the quotes and do port: {{ port | int }}

Comment: Be aware that you cannot do what William D Irons is saying because when YAML sees `port: {` it expects that to be an object literal, just like JSON, versus a jinja2 template which is `port: {{`, so you _must_ use some kind of YAML quoting; either `'{{ port | int }}'` or `port: >-\n    {{ port | int }}` etc. We will need more details about why `"{{ port | int }}" <-- not work`

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel `"{{ port | int }}"` not work as a number, only as a string. My problem is because to value is string. I need that `{{ port | int }}` was number. But reading the documentation, I look this:
```
Values passed in using the key=value syntax are interpreted as strings. Use the JSON format if you need to pass in anything that shouldn’t be a string (Booleans, integers, floats, lists etc).``` :-(

Comment: I tried some string manipulation with JSON strings. It is ugly, but maybe help.
https://gist.github.com/leonardonsantos/885a7e116d9f36ed9a98efb107794015

Answer (score 3):

Actually it seems not possible to convert jinja template into integer since it always return string to Ansible. Detailed explanation here :
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/9362#issuecomment-302432118

However, I found a workaround consisting of using folded string bloc in yaml. In your case the Ansible task should look like this :

```yaml
- name: Create inputenter code here
  uri:
    url: "https://{{ url_graylog }}/api/system/inputs"
    ...
    body_format: json
    body: >
      {
        "title": "{{ name }}",
        "configuration": {
          "bind_address": "0.0.0.0",
          "port": {{ port | int }}
        }
      }
    global: true
```

It is a little bit less readable but will produce a non-quoted value for port. The body sent looks like this :

```
...
"body": {
    "configuration": {
        "bind_address": "0.0.0.0",
        "port": 25565
    },
    "title": "My title"
},
...
```

Hope it helped !

Comment: This worked, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You can set in ansible.cfg:
`jinja2_native = True`

Comment: Bear in mind this is a global setting implying a global impact.

Comment: with `jinja2_native=True` encrypted values (`$ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256...`) will no longer be decrypted (tested on ansible v2.10.5)

Answer (score 1):

Create your variable as such:

```
    variableName:
      name: "demo"
      capacityUnits: 1
```

Then body like this:

```
body: "{{ variableName | to_json }}"
```

Then the int will persist:

```
"body": "{\"name\": \"demo\", \"capacityUnits\": 1}"
```